# In-lining InvocationExpressions

Tags: c#, functional-programming

This is regards to one of my answers: [Linq Expression Calling Combines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408179/linq-expression-calling-combines/34416123#34416123). The question wasn't very well received, but it proved to be an interesting task that I enjoyed working on.

I ended up with the following:

```
public static class ExpressionHelpers
{
    public static TExpressionType InlineInvokes<TExpressionType>(this TExpressionType expression)
        where TExpressionType : Expression
    {
        return (TExpressionType)new InvokeInliner().Inline(expression);
    }

    public static Expression InlineInvokes(this InvocationExpression expression)
    {
        return new InvokeInliner().Inline(expression);
    }

    public class InvokeInliner : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private Stack<Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression>> _context = new Stack<Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression>>();
        public Expression Inline(Expression expression)
        {
            return Visit(expression);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitInvocation(InvocationExpression e)
        {
            var callingLambda = e.Expression as LambdaExpression;
            if (callingLambda == null) //Fix as per comment
                return base.VisitInvocation(e);
            var currentMapping = new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression>();
            for (var i = 0; i < e.Arguments.Count; i++)
            {
                var argument = Visit(e.Arguments[i]);
                var parameter = callingLambda.Parameters[i];
                if (parameter != argument)
                    currentMapping.Add(parameter, argument);
            }
            _context.Push(currentMapping);
            var result = Visit(callingLambda.Body);
            _context.Pop();
            return result;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression e)
        {
            if (_context.Count > 0)
            {
                var currentMapping = _context.Peek();
                if (currentMapping.ContainsKey(e))
                    return currentMapping[e];
            }
            return e;
        }
    }
}
```

At its core, it simply in-lines `Invoke()` calls in the expression tree, replacing them with the called expression's code verbatim.

Examples:

```
INPUT:
Invoke(i => (i + 1), 3)

OUTPUT:
(3 + 1)  

INPUT: 
i => Invoke((i, j) => (i * j), Invoke(i => (i + 1), i), Invoke(i => (i + 2), i))

OUTPUT:
i => ((i + 1) * (i + 2))

INPUT:  
b => Invoke((d, e) => (d * e), Invoke(b => (50 + Invoke(z => (25 + Invoke(h => (h * 8), z)), b)), b), Invoke(c => (c + 2), b))  

OUTPUT:   
b => ((50 + (25 + (b * 8))) * (b + 2))
```

Example usage:

```
Expression<Func<int, int>> f1 = i => i + 1;
Expression<Func<int, int>> f2 = i => i + 2;
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> f3 = (i, j) => i * j;

var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
var r = Expression
    .Invoke(f3, new[] { 
        Expression.Invoke(f1, p), 
        Expression.Invoke(f2, p) }) 
    .InlineInvokes();

Expression<Func<int, int>> lam = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(r, p);
```

The only 'issue' I can come up with is that if one were to modify `f1` after `InlineInvokes()` was called, they might be surprised if they were expecting `f1` to be captured and lazily executed, but in my opinion, this is probably to be expected (any other opinions?).

In summary, my questions are:

1. Are there any pitfalls in in-lining invocations (that is, is my idea fundamentally flawed, and cannot be solved 'properly')?
2. Are there any issues with the code I've written itself?

Comment: After codereview.SE / rubberduck debugging, I have found a case where it does fail: `Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(new Func<int>(() => 5))).InlineInvokes()` - Are there any others?

Comment: What are the benefits of doing this? Why would I need it? Can you name a few examples where this is useful and how to apply it?

Comment: @t3chb0t I suppose the most common reason would be with Entity Framework, as it does not allow `Expression.Invoke` in the expression tree. Personally, I have used the above code when writing an expression tree parser and encountering an Invoke expression - our output doesn't care whether or not the expression was invoked, so we simply inline the invokes. As for having to use Expression.Invoke - it's useful if you want to apply a delegate to an existing `IQueryable<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this code a few times, and recently was thinking through a scenario where the above will fail:

```
var iParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var lParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));

var original = Expression.Invoke(
    Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Invoke(
                Expression.Lambda(
                    Expression.Add(iParam, lParam),
                    iParam),
                Expression.Constant(1)
        ),
        lParam),
    Expression.Constant(2)
);
var transformed = original.InlineInvokes();
```

The original can be visualized as:

```
Invoke(Param_0 => Invoke(Param_1 => (Param_1 + Param_0), 1), 2)
```

Here, the inner invocation is using a parameter from its parent. Since we're using a stack to represent the mappings between parameters, we're not taking into consideration `Param_0`. Here's the current output:

```
(1 + Param_0)
```

Here's the fixed code:

```
protected override Expression VisitInvocation(InvocationExpression e)
{
    var callingLambda = e.Expression as LambdaExpression;
    if (callingLambda == null)
        return base.VisitInvocation(e);
    var currentMapping = new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression>();
    for (var i = 0; i < e.Arguments.Count; i++)
    {
        var argument = Visit(e.Arguments[i]);
        var parameter = callingLambda.Parameters[i];
        if (parameter != argument)
            currentMapping.Add(parameter, argument);
    }
    if (_context.Count > 0)
    {
        var existingContext = _context.Peek();
        foreach (var kvp in existingContext)
        {
            if (!currentMapping.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
                currentMapping[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
        }
    }

    _context.Push(currentMapping);
    var result = Visit(callingLambda.Body);
    _context.Pop();
    return result;
}
```

Note that we only propagate the parameters if they don't already exist. This is required in situations as follows:

```
var iParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var lParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));

var original = Expression.Invoke(
    Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Invoke(
                Expression.Lambda(
                    Expression.Add(iParam, lParam),
                    iParam, lParam),
                Expression.Constant(1), Expression.Constant(3)
        ),
        lParam),
    Expression.Constant(2)
);
```

```
Invoke(Param_0 => Invoke((Param_1, Param_0) => (Param_1 + Param_0), 1, 3), 2)
```

Here, the inner invoke is providing a value for `Param_0` which takes precedence over what the outer invoke is providing. If we compile that expression (without inlining) - we see the result is `4`.

Thus, we must ensure that we only add parameters from our parent context *if* we haven't already been provided them.